# control webview zoom out at 100% in android

Tags: android, webview, zooming

In my app I am getting url of an image and  I am loading that in webview. Here is if i zoomout at initial stage(like 100%) it should not zoom out. But once the zoom in has occured then it should be zoom out and here also it should not zoom out when it reaches to first position means(100%).

How can I achieve this. Can anyone help me.